# anko value initialize with rxAndroid

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I want editText 'B' get text from 'A' when 'A' text changed with anko

So I made function get two edit text value with Rxandroid

```
val A = editText {

                textChangedListener {
                    addTextinB(this@editText,B)
                }
            }
val B = editText {
                hint = "should be changed "
            }

fun addTextinB(v: EditText, v2:EditText) {
      RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(v)
                .debounce(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe { tvChangeEvent ->
                    v2.setText(tvChangeEvent.view().text)
   }
```

But when I run, I see "Property B should be initialized before get" 
I think B should Initialized before call addTextinB, So I changed.

```
var A by Delegates.notNull<EditText>()
var B by Delegates.notNull<EditText>()

 override fun onCreateView(){
   //anko Code here 
   ... 
          A=editText {...}
          B=editText {...}
 }
```

but fail again.

When I changed A,B are nullable, 
there is no error message but addTextinB function not work

finally I changed addTextinB, and everyting is ok

```
fun addTextinB(v: EditText ) {
  RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(v)
            .debounce(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe { tvChangeEvent ->
                B.setText(tvChangeEvent.view().text)
}
```

I'm wonder there is way to get two parameter.